# How do you match a line which starts with a special character using grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have many .txt files in my directory which contain the lines starting with '='

For ex:
a.txt has the following line( with spaces initially)

```
        =putSomething here;
```

How do I write a grep query which will match the above line?
I tried the following,

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -rn "^[=].*$"
```

Answer (score 2):

A line that begins with `=` translates to the regex `^=`.

Your find command should then be:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep '^='
```

Or, better (avoid useless use of `xargs`):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep '^[[:space:]]*=' {} +
```

(here, due to the ending `+`, only one grep is executed for a bunch of files)

Comment: user1449951 wrote _with spaces initially_.

Comment: There are spaces initially and hence the above option didn't work. I tried grep -irn '^ *=' **/*txt

Comment: @Arrow Thank you for fixing my last command, answer updated. Note that I never escape nor quote the ending `+` on Linux. If this is a problem on other systems, feel free to fix my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this sample file:

```
$ cat file.txt
        =putSomething here;
```

Now, to find all such `.txt` files in the current directory:

```
$ grep -n '^[[:space:]]*=' *.txt
file.txt:1:        =putSomething here;
```

If you want to find all such `.txt` files in the current directory and *all of its subdirectories*, then use:

```
$ grep -rn '^[[:space:]]*=' --include '*.txt'
subdir/another.txt:1:        =putSomething here;
file.txt:1:        =putSomething here;
```

#### Notes

1. `find` and `xargs` are not needed here.  With the `-r` option, `grep` does recursive searching through subdirectories.
2. `--include '*.txt'` limits `grep` to files matching the glob `*.txt`.
3. `^` matches at the beginning of a line.  `[[:space:]]*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.  `=` matches an equal sign.  In POSIX regular expressions, there is nothing special about `=` so it can be treated as any other character.
4. Ending a grep regex with `.*$` does not change which lines are matched.   `.*$` matches either if any characters or if no characters follow.  The only reason to use `.*$` is to change what grep highlights as matched text.

Comment: Find and glob are not equivalent because of the difference on how they treat dot-files, how and when they follow symlinks, and globing is affected by some options like GLOBIGNORE.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the below command and it seems to work.

```
grep -rn '^ *=' **/*txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to recursive `grep` and `xargs`:

```
$ find /dir -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -q '^[[:space:]]*=' {} ';' -print
```

This will look in `/dir` (and below) for all regular files whose names matches the given pattern.  For each such file, if `grep -q '^[[:space:]]*='` exits with a zero exit status (the pattern was matched somewhere in the file), then its name is outputted.

Or, if you just want to see the lines themselves:

```
$ find /dir -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep '^[[:space:]]*=' {} '+'
```

The `+` at the end will feed as many filenames as possible to each invocation to `grep` whereas using `;` as in my first example would feed only one file at a time.